# Protect Sqlite file in IOS, not using SQLCipher

Tags: ios, sqlite

Beside using SQLCipher, is there any way to protect a sqlite file?

I found that when I open my sqlite file, there is a button ("File"->"Encrypt") that lets me enter the encrypt key. But I don't know in my project in Xcode how I can set the decrypt key to open my database.

Comment: What are you trying to protect against and have you thought about / researched how effective you will be at achieving that level of protection?

Comment: I just want to protect against average developer, because my project is not very big. But i still want to hide my database. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: In a word, no.  You can attempt to decrypt the file on opening your app and encrypt on exit, but that's easily circumvented.

Comment: Can you show me how to do, because this is my first project i just want to do some thing really simple and fast.

Comment: SQLCipher is only as complicated as it needs to be. If that is too complicated, you are unlikely to implement a secure system on your own.

Answer (score 0):

Don't encrypt the whole file. Just encrypt the data you store that is deemed to be sensitive.

Core Data value transformers are easy to write and can be specified within the Core Data model. They will transform the data as it goes into, and comes out of the relational database' fields.

See [`NSValueTransformer`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSValueTransformer_Class/Reference/Reference.html), for example: [NSValueTranformer to encrypt data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10685196/nsvaluetranformer-to-encrypt-data)

Comment: Can i encrypt the whole file? Because i just only use select query in my project, there is no insert or update. I just want to do some thing simple, because this is my first project. it is good for me if after user jailbreak their phone then they dont see my where is my database or they open them but it is encrypted with a password. Plz help me Thank you ver much.

Comment: Sorry I can't help I've only used value transformers at this stage.